# RobotFramework DataBase Library Access Query Results columns as Key Value Pair

Tags: robotframework

Hi I am using Database Library and Query Keyword to fetch the data from Database. The results that I am getting is by default List of values and to access the value I need to use  the Index references like [0][1].
But I want to access my column values as [0].id.

I found the argument returnAsDict which gives the columnname and value, but still it is a List variable only and not a dictionary Variable.
I am not sure whether I am missing something here. Please help

Robot File Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DatabaseLibrary
*** Variables ***
*** Test Cases ***
TC1:WorkingModel
    Connect To Database     psycopg2    ${DBNAME}    ${DBUSER}    ${DBPASS}    ${DBHOST}    ${YB-DBPORT}
    @{output}  Query    select id,description,sourcefrom test.details where id= '9TC1RDREG';
    Log To Console  ${output[0][0]}
    Disconnect From Database
TC2:ExpectedModel
    Connect To Database     psycopg2    ${DBNAME}    ${DBUSER}    ${DBPASS}    ${DBHOST}    ${YB-DBPORT}
    &{output}  Query    select id,description,sourcefrom test.details where id= '9TC1RDREG';  returnAsDict=True
    Log To Console  ${output[0].id}
    Disconnect From Database
```

Results:

```
==============================================================================
TC1:WorkingModel                                                      ..9TC1RDREG
TC1:WorkingModel                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC2:ExpectedModel                                                     | FAIL |
Cannot set variable '&{output}': Expected dictionary-like value, got list.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test-Stack                                                            | FAIL |
2 tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually see in the [DatabaseLibrary documentation](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.2/DatabaseLibrary.html#Query) that the values are returned as a *list of dictionaries*. This would mean that the returned value is still a list, which you'll need to handle as such but each index within that list contains a dictionary of any keys and values on that specific row of data.

Consider a simplified example of the returned content

```
# The list as it would be returned normally
["value", "anothervalue"]

# The list when using returnAsDict = True
[{"key": "value"}, {"anotherkey": "anothervalue"}]
```

You'll need to still access the list index first and then look into the dictionary whether the value you want to get is there. This means that the dictionary approach will require more steps but does maintain an explicit connection between the values as they can be returned from the list in single dictionary.

As an example following should work

```
TC2:ExpectedModel
    Connect To Database     psycopg2    ${DBNAME}    ${DBUSER}    ${DBPASS}
    ...    ${DBHOST}    ${YB-DBPORT}
    @{output}=    Query    select id, description, source from test.details where id= '9TC1RDREG';
    ...    returnAsDict=True
    Log To Console    ${output[0]}     # Log one dictionary entry from the list
    &{dict_0}=    Create Dictionary    &{output[0]}
    Log To Console    ${dict_0["id"]}  # Log single key from the dictionary on index 0
    Disconnect From Database
```

Comment: Hi  Morkkis, I tried this approach and it worked for me.. Thank you really for the help.